# How do I keep browsers out of my libraries? Where should they be placed?

Tags: php, security

Through researching, I discovered two common techniques to prevent clients from accessing libraries directly with a browser:

1. Use `.htaccess` to keep them out
2. Define a constant and pass it to included files, included files then checks if the constant exists.

However, just keeping those files out of the document root seems sensible. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best thing to do is keep it outside of your docroot.  There is no reason to put includes in a directly HTTP-accessible place.

Some shared web hosts are poorly configured and don't have this option, but most do, and you definitely have this choice on your own server or VPS.

Comment: It would make method 2 unnecessary.

Comment: There are no performance issues with this at all.  As @Blake said, the `.htaccess` file doesn't matter, as the server cannot access that folder anyway.  The web server doesn't know or care where PHP gets its includes... that's up to the PHP configuration.  The web server only knows about what is within its doc root.

Answer (score 3):

To complete the Brad's answer, here is how you could organize your folders:

```
/path/to/project/
  public_html/
    index.php
  includes/
    includes.php
```

Your webserver's root folder would be `public_html`.

If you can't modify this structure, the only acceptable way is to use a `.htaccess` (or equivalent) to prevent `includes` to be accessed publicly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an Apache Webserver, you could deny the access to all .inc.php files. you only have to add the following to your Apache Vhost config:

```
<FilesMatch .inc.php>
   Order allow, deny
   deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

You can still include these files in your php code.

Answer (score 0):

If the library files just define classes / functions / whatever, and your server isn't configured in a way that makes it possible to view the source, then nothing would be achieved by requesting the scripts via the web server anyway. That being said, if you can you might as well store them outside of the document root.

Comment: Ever been bitten by a host that broke their PHP configuration?  It's not fun if all your source code and DB passwords get dumped to the web by accident.  At least if the bulk of everything is out of the web root, damage is minimized.

Comment: @Brad That would be an example of the server being configured in a way that makes it possible to view the source, but admittedly one that you wouldn't be able to foresee or control as a developer. Yes, that would suck. I endorse storing the files outside of the document root. My points are that for a properly configured server, requesting library files that just have code like class definitions won't do anything, and that for such library files OP's technique #2 won't accomplish anything.